# Example for bias in experiments due to "social pressure"

Tags: history

I remember the example for the bias in experiments:

A famous physicist got a wrong result for a constant. Due to his fame, the published results of other experimenters only slowly reached the correct value after many years. (Presumably, results that were too far from the "known" value were just not published.)

However, I do not remember the name of the measured quantity and would be grateful for a pointer.

Answer to comments (I cannot comment):
Yes, Millikan is the one I was looking for. Reading wikipedia makes it clear that I must have read it in the Feynman book. Thank you.

Comment: This indeed would be an interesting example to cite, but could you put some more detail in to help someone answer. What was the constant (its meaning or name, not value)? If you can't recall this, what field of research was this in? Even a basic, coarse field description may help.

Comment: This could easily describe the Hubble constant as measured by Hubble himself (**way** off initially, since his data was pure noise), or the electron charge as measured by Millikan (he was slightly off but considerably underestimated his uncertainties), or probably a ton of other examples.

Comment: I think that has been asked on the site already. Not sure how to search on it though.

Comment: I think Chris is right with the Milikan expample.

Comment: Yep - I believe the electron example is the correct one (or at least one of many)

Comment: I'll will not take the risk of 10 downvotes, but you can apply this reading grid to the proof of the superposition through photons Bell experiments ( while it is well proved with electrons experiments )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This could easily describe the Hubble constant as measured by Hubble himself (**way** off initially, since his data was pure noise), or the electron charge as measured by [Millikan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Andrews_Millikan#Data_selection_controversy) (he was slightly off but considerably underestimated his uncertainties), or probably a ton of other examples.

–  Chris White 15 hours ago

Answer (score 0):

Be wary of simple stories with simple morals. History is never that kind to storytellers.

The oscillating and drifting measured values of physical constants is extremely common. In an article in Quanta magazine ([New Measurement Deepens Proton Puzzle](https://www.quantamagazine.org/20160811-new-measurement-deepens-proton-radius-puzzle/)), Dr. Randolf Pohl shows a series of plots of the historical measured values of [a dozen physical constants](http://pdg.lbl.gov/2012/reviews/rpp2012-rev-history-plots.pdf) (PDF link). Two examples below:
[image: Historical measured values of the free neutron lifetime and the eta meson mass]

The reason for these oscillations is the refinement of measuring techniques and the invention of new ones. Other illustrative examples are the [astronomical unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astronomical_unit#History) and the [speed of light](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speed_of_light#History). Unless all physicists are starstruck by their predecessors, the real story is more complicated.

Comment: I believe the two examples here are good but I would likw stress and important point. In the above example all the data is consistent as the measure fall within each others confidence interval. In the case of "social pressure", the error of the measurement should not put the first measurements "within on errobar" of the "final" result